# twitter python developer codes

Tags: python, twitterapi-python

in the process of extracting tweets from a twitter account, should the access keys be regenerated again and again ?
like i have tried this code:

```
import tweepy as tw
import pandas as pd

consumer_key = "xyz"
consumer_secret = "xyz"
access_token = "xyz"
access_token_secret = "xyz"
auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tw.API(auth)

tweets = []
likes = []
time = []
cursor = tw.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id='CirusFoundation', tweet_mode = "extended").items(1)
for i in tw.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id='CirusFoundation', tweet_mode = "extended").items(200):
    tweets.append(i.full_text)
    likes.append(i.favourite_count)
    time.append(i.created_at)

df = pd.DataFrame({'tweets':tweets, 'likes':likes, 'time':time})
```

now i get a forbidden: 403 error. as output
thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for a 403:

1. You are requesting a feature that is not covered by your twitter dev account. Tweepy may be predecated on having the elevated access.
2. You are trying to access from a non-ssl/https
3. You have exceeded your request quota.
4. Your access token was not generated properly (E.g if you are trying to write, you need to generate with r/w permissions)

Comment: mhm, thanks for the info i've applied for the elevated dev application and will receive the result in 2 days :) Thank you